# Ionic - Botões personalizados no google maps

Tags: ionic3, maps, floatingactionbutton

Estou usando ionic para criar um app onde uso a api do google maps eu preciso colocar alguns botões flutuando sobre esse mapa, como na imagem. [image: Exemplo de botões no mapa]

Eu achei um pedaço de código que parece ter funcionado pra pessoa, mas aqui comigo não funciona, parece que o botão fica atrás do mapa. Tentei aumentar o z-index, mas não consegui. Tentei também criar os botões dentro da div do #map, mas não aparecem.

Vou deixar o código para verem como estou tentando fazer.

```
initMap(lat, lng) {
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
  zoom: 16,
  center: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
  mapTypeControl: true,
  streetViewControl: true,
  fullscreenControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
})

//### Add a button on Google Maps ...
var controlMarkerUI = document.createElement('DIV');
controlMarkerUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlMarkerUI.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://localhost/car.png)";
controlMarkerUI.style.height = '28px';
controlMarkerUI.style.width = '25px';
controlMarkerUI.style.top = '11px';
controlMarkerUI.style.left = '120px';
controlMarkerUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
//myLocationControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(controlMarkerUI);}
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Ionic utiliza html para renderização dos elementos na tela, você pode criar os botões e posicioná-los com 'position: fixed' sobre o elemento do mapa.